# Что такое "тестовый контур" и откуда взялось это словосочетание?

Tags: терминология, история

Иногда приходится слышать выражение "тестовый контур" (в контексте какой-либо тестовой программной среды). Интересна история происхождения этого выражения. Википедия по этому вопросу хранит молчание и гугл тоже.

UPD (перенесено из комментариев): *довольно много народа употребляет данный термин и никто не может внятно объяснить откуда он взялся. Тем не менее, наверняка у этого "устойчивого выражения" интересная история*

Comment: скорее всего это выражение с Вашего локального окружения. Не удивлюсь, если придумали люди, которые связаны с электроникой.

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, в it'шной среде слышал такое не раз и в совершенно разных компаниях/локациях. Так что точно не "локальное окружение"

Comment: @alexanderbarakin довольно много народа употребляет данный термин и никто не может внятно объяснить откуда он взялся. Тем не менее, наверняка у этого "устойчивого выражения" интересная история

Comment: Жаргонизм из электроники, ещё с ламповых времен. Поищите в Гугл "гетеродинный контур", "контур с обратной связью", "электронный контур".

Comment: @KAGGDesign а какая связь с "тестовый контур"? общее слово "контур" это еще не все, нужно объяснение почему "гетеродинный контур" и "тестовый контур" взаимосвязаны (если это так). Я поискал пересечений не увидел пока ...

Comment: Вв спросите тех, кто занимался электроникой. "Собрать тестовый контур" значило собрать электрическую цепь для тестов.

Answer (score 2):

Однозначной терминологии в данном вопросе не существует. *Контур* может оказаться *средой* или *окружением*, вместо *теста* и *продакта* официальная документация может ссылаться на *контур опытной эксплуатации* и *контур промышленной эксплуатации*.

На терминологию влияет и процесс разработки, которые практикует команда или целая организация. Обычно все программисты разрабатывают и тестируют код на своих компьютерах и имеют всё необходимое окружение для этого, например, локальные версии MySQL, Redis или MongoDB. Если разработка ведётся через Docker, то необходимые сервера запускаются в контейнерах локально.

Этот контур может называться *локальным* или *персональным*. Его хватает проверить, что программист, кажется, написал всё так, как предполагалось. Там можно прогнать модульные и интеграционные тесты.

Когда задача завершена программистом, он отправляет код в общий репозиторий, из которого собирается версия проекта, которая на жаргоне называется *дев* (**dev**elopment). Этот контур позволяет проверить, что программисты ничего не сломали друг у друга, он достаточно нестабилен. Здесь выполняются автоматизированные интеграционные тесты.

Когда программисты считают, что код можно отдавать на тестирование, они переносят изменения на *тестовые контур*, где можно прогонять ручные тесты. Здесь возникают тонкости, связанные с тем, что тестирование бывает очень разным, например, нагрузочным. Для нагрузочных тестов обычно создают свой собственный контур.

Когда всё готово, проверенная версия попадает на *прод* (**prod**uction), он же *контур промышленной эксплуатации*.

Что такое *контур* или *среда* физически? Зависит от средства разработки и от технологий. Часто это Docker-контейнеры, которые разворачиваются на нескольких виртуальных машинах. Для каждого контура мы создаём несколько виртуалок, и запускаем там очередную версию кода.

Если вы работаете в Azure, вы можете сделать несколько серверов БД, каждый для своего окружения. Такие ресурсы можно сгруппировать, назвав группы *dev*, *test* и *prod*.

Если проект разрабатывается давно, и туда уже невозможно внедрить контейнерную разработку, под каждый контур системные администраторы могут выделить несколько разных физических серверов, управляя ими вручную. Трудоёмки, но такие контуры тоже встречаются, потому что некоторые проекты существуют по 15-20 лет.

Answer (score -2):

Кажется, что термин исходит из российского enterprise. Слово "контур" предполагает наличие замкнутого цикла и применимо к инженерным системам с обратной связью. Например, можно говорить о контурах при разборе электрических цепей с помощью [правил Кирхгофа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0).

В IT контексте я лично не вижу чего-то циклического в окружениях/средах  и считаю использование термина "контур" неуместным.